# AngularJS basic search filter

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I currently have a very basic page:

```
<h4>{{event.name}}</h4>
<p>{{event.desc}}</p>
<p>At: {{event.venue.name}}</p>
```

and I want to add a search function to search for the name, desc, venue.name, etc... How can I do this?

```
<ul class="">
<li ng-repeat="event in events | filter:query">
  {{events.name}}
</li>
</ul>
```

This doesn't seem to filter anything. thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] along with proper explanation of expected behavior

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a model to the query parameter

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" />

<li ng-repeat="event in events | filter: query">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom filter in your template:

```
<li ng-repeat="event in events | filter:search ">
     {{events.name}}
 </li>
```

And in your controller add the custom search method:

```
$scope.search = function (event) {
   //$scope.searchString is the model of matching string input field
   var query = $scope.searchString.toLowerCase(),
       fullText = event.name.toLowerCase() + ' ' + event.venue.toLowerCase() + event.desc.toLowerCase();

   if (fullText.indexOf(query) != -1) {
        return true;
   }
   return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("Profile", [] );
                app.controller("ProfileCtrl", function($scope) {        
                        $scope.events  = [{name:'thara','desc':'I am thara from india',venue:{'name':'india'}},{name:'Raj','desc':'I am Raj from america',venue:{'name':'America'}},{name:'john','desc':'I am john from newzealan',venue:{'name':'newzealan'}}]
                        $scope.filter_val = {};
                        $scope.own_filter = function(eachvalue){
                                if(!$scope.filter_val.value)
                                        return true;
                                else{
                                        var all_value = ''
                                        for(key in eachvalue){
                                                if(eachvalue[key])
                                                        all_value =all_value+eachvalue[key];
                                        }
                                        var search_val  = $scope.filter_val.value.toLocaleLowerCase()
                                        all_value       = all_value.toLocaleLowerCase()
                                        if(all_value.indexOf(search_val) != -1){
                                                return true;
                                        }else
                                                return false
                                }
                        }
                })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Profile" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
                <input type="text" ng-model="filter_val.value">
                <div class="row" ng-repeat="event in events |filter:own_filter track by $index">
                        <h4>{{event.name}}</h4>
                        <p>{{event.desc}}</p>
                        <p>At: {{event.venue.name}}</p>
                </div>
        </body>
```